# Cookie not sent with JSONP request in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, jsonp

I have some JavaScript hosted on domain A that makes JSONP requests to a service on domain B. A request to B/Auth sets a cookie containing an authentication token. Subsequent requests to other services on domain B should also contain this cookie.

In Chrome this mechanism works perfectly; the cookie is set, sent, and data is returned. In IE10 the Set-Cookie header comes back with the response from B/Auth but is not included with subsequent requests.

```
Set-Cookie  MINT_SESSIONTOKEN=MyDST={TOKEN}; expires=Thu, 10-Oct-2013 11:57:45 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

After some Googling and experimentation I discovered that if I set IE's privacy settings (Internet Options > Privacy) to Low or Accept All Cookies then the cookie is sent with subsequent requests to domain B. Any setting higher than Low prevents the cookie from being sent.

While this solves the issue for me it does not solve the problem for users who would have to reconfigure their privacy settings in order to get data.

I'm a bit confused as to what exactly is happening under the hood. I think IE sees the cookie as third party and prevents it from being set (despite the cookie being set for, and sent to, domain B) which is why it is omitted in subsequent requests.

Is there something I can do to prevent IE from blocking the cookie without the user having to modify their browser privacy settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I needed a Compact Privacy policy.

http://www.p3pwriter.com/LRN_111.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.marco.org/2007/04/27/p3p-sucks-how-to-get-frame-cookies-unblocked-in-ie6